# Why txtDisplay() method not found?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java calculator. I write my code in netbeans. When i build my source code it show me error:

> **C:\Users\Nishan\Documents\javawork\Calculator\src\Calculation\Calculation.java:215:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       txtDisplay.setText(btn1Text);   symbol:   variable txtDisplay   location: class Calculation**

Here is my code:

```
private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    String btn1Text;
    btn1Text = txtDisplay.getText() + btn1.getText();
txtDisplay.setText(btn1Text);
}



  **/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Calculation;

/**
 *
 * @author Nishan
 */
public class Calculation extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    double firstnum;
    double secondnum;
    double result;
    String operation;
    public Calculation() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btn1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn13 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn14 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn15 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn16 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn18 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn17 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);

        btn1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn1.setText("1");
        btn1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btn2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn2.setText("2");

        btn3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn3.setText("3");

        btn4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn4.setText("+");

        btn5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn5.setText("4");

        btn6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn6.setText("5");

        btn7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn7.setText("6");

        btn8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn8.setText("-");

        btn9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn9.setText("7");

        btn10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn10.setText("8");

        btn11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn11.setText("9");

        btn12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn12.setText("*");

        btn13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn13.setText(".");

        btn14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn14.setText("0");

        btn15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn15.setText("C");

        btn16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn16.setText("/");

        btn18.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn18.setText("=");

        btn17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        btn17.setText("+-/");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btn1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btn2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btn3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btn4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btn14)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(btn13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                    .addComponent(btn5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(btn9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(btn6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(btn10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(btn7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(btn11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(btn8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(btn12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                                .addComponent(btn15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(btn16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(btn18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(btn17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(125, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btn1)
                    .addComponent(btn2)
                    .addComponent(btn3)
                    .addComponent(btn4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btn5)
                    .addComponent(btn6)
                    .addComponent(btn7)
                    .addComponent(btn8))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btn9)
                    .addComponent(btn10)
                    .addComponent(btn11)
                    .addComponent(btn12))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btn14)
                    .addComponent(btn13)
                    .addComponent(btn15)
                    .addComponent(btn16))
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addComponent(btn18)
                .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(240, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btn17)
                    .addGap(23, 23, 23)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String btn1Text;
        btn1Text = txtDisplay.getText() + btn1.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(btn1Text);
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calculation().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btn1;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn10;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn11;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn12;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn13;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn14;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn15;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn16;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn17;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn18;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn2;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn3;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn4;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn5;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn6;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn7;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn8;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn9;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
**
```

Comment: where did you define `txtDisplay`?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. My guess is that `txtDisplay` is declared as a *local* variable somewhere.

Comment: method ?you used it like a variable ?

Comment: As i am new to java i have a little knowledge. I added the full code. Please check this.

Comment: there is no variable `txtDisplay`, so your compiler tells you so. It can´t acces methods of non existing variables. you might want to do `jTextField1#method`.

Comment: @NishanSingha change `txtDisplay` to `jTextField1` . also txtDisplay is not a method it's a variable

Comment: @FastSnail It works, many many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have variable txtDisplay in your class. Add it.
And yes, it's not a method, it's a variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must initialise your txtDisplay in order to perform any operations on it.

What kind of display are you trying to implement?

If you are trying to implement a single line entry display;

- import the package `JTextField` with this code    `import javax.swing.JTextArea;`
- Initialise the JTextArea with  `JTextArea txtDisplay = new JTextArea();`

If you are trying to implement a multiple line display; follow the same steps, replacing JTextField with JTextArea.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html.